# Which of the following $u=\sqrt{c+1} - \sqrt{c}$ and $v=\sqrt{c} - \sqrt{c-1}$ is greater?

Tags: calculus

If

$$u=\sqrt{c+1} - \sqrt{c}$$

and

$$v=\sqrt{c} - \sqrt{c-1}$$

then, which among $u$ and $v$ is greater?

***Please help without substituting values.***

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint:  try a few values...that should at least tell you what the answer is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt x$ is concave function, so $$2\sqrt x \gt \sqrt {x-1} + \sqrt {x+1}$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: Multiply $u$ by $\frac {\sqrt{c+1}+\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{c+1}+\sqrt{c}}$ and $v$ by $\frac {\sqrt{c-1}+\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{c-1}+\sqrt{c}}$

Answer (score 2):

$u=\frac{(\sqrt{c+1}-\sqrt{c})(\sqrt{c+1}+\sqrt{c})}{\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{c+1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{c+1}}$

By analogy.
$v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{c-1}}$.

So,$v>u$